# Extract OrderID from Text MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, user-defined-functions

I want to extract a number like this 306-3584295-9664328 from a text column. The format is always the same, but in front of the number could be text after this number as well. For ex.

```
Blblblbla xxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx Blblalblala
```

I found a regex for this \w\d{2}-?\d{7}-?\d{7} but I cant use it with mysql.

What I want to achieve is to extract this number from one column and add it to a new column. Just the number.

Everything I tried so far was not successful. 
Unfortunately, I'm still a beginner and hope you might be able to help me.

Bye , Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` frunction to replace non-numeric val - it'll work mysql 8+ version/MariaDB

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=66712f05e397aa9fbed61f78037fd436)

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('Blblblbla 234-4565979-4564646 Blblalblala','[a-zA-Z]+', '') as content
```

For inserting into table you can use below code

```
insert into tablename(textval,orderid) 
   select 'Blblblbla 234-4565979-4564646 Blblalblala' as textval,REGEXP_REPLACE ('Blblblbla 234-4565979-4564646 Blblalblala','[a-zA-Z]+', '') as orderid
```

OR in case your table - just replace tablename and column name with your desired table and column name

```
insert into testtable(textval,orderid) 
       select colname as textval,REGEXP_REPLACE (colname,'[a-zA-Z]+', '') as orderid from tablename
```

Comment: Thanks fa06. Unfortunatelly i can´t use mysql 8, only mariadb. Is there a similar statement to solve my problem?

Comment: what is your maiadb version @ChristianMazilu

Comment: Mariadb 10.2.17

Comment: @ChristianMazilu, it'll work in mariadb also- check here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=66712f05e397aa9fbed61f78037fd436

Comment: I would use '[a-zA-Z ]+' (notice the extra space in the end) in order to remove spaces before and after the number.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help. But I need to write this number in a new/other column. Should I use an update statement to do this?

Comment: @ChristianMazilu, do you want to insert in in new column or update any column value ? And if it helped you please mark it as accepted answer

Comment: It should be inserted in a new or existing column.

Comment: @ChristianMazilu, I've provider insert statement - you can check

Comment: I only can test it tomorrow. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Hi fa06, tried it but without success. 
There is a strange error message that a value is not defined in another column.


I want the following:

Table = s_order

Column with order number (regex: text 123-1234567.1234567 text) = internalcomment

Column to be inserted = paymentid

Can you help me with that?